# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in sendmail.php

Tags: php, jquery, sendmail, contact-form

let me apologize in advance, i just jumped into the jquery thing like yesterday, so speak slowly and use lots of beginner terms. anyway, im trying to make my jquery/ajax contact form stop refreshing and stay on the same page, but i keep receiving an error reading "ReferenceError: $ is not defined". i trying to fix this and figure out if it is related to my failure here.

here is the HTML......

```
<div id="contact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="contactContainer">
                <h3>Get in touch:</h3>
                <div class="contact">

                    <form action="js/ajaxcontactform/sendmail.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                    <label for="name">Name:<font color="#ff3300">*</font></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <label for="email">Email:<font color="#ff3300">*</font></label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <label for="tele">Telephone:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="tele" value="" id="tele" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="special" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="last">Don't fill this in:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last" value="" id="last" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <label for="message">Message:<font color="#ff3300">*</font></label><textarea rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submitbutton">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Message" />
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    </form>
```

here is the php.....

```
    <?php

// basic settings section
$sendto = 'your@email.com';
$subject = 'You have a new message from your virtual resume!';
$iserrormessage = 'There was a problem with sending e-mail to us, please check:';
$thanks = "Thank's for your message! I'll contact you as soon as possible!";

$emptyname = 'Did you enter your name?';
$emptyemail = 'Did you enter your e-mail address?';
$emptymessage = 'Did you enter the message?';
$emptyphone = 'Did you enter phone number?';

$alertname = 'Please enter your name with standard alphabet!';
$alertemail = 'Please enter your e-maill address in format: name@domain.com';
$alertmessage = "Please do not use any parenthesis or other escaping characters. Standard web url's should work fine!";
$alertphone = 'Please enter your phone number without any special characters, only numbers ex: 5553212';

$alert = '';
$iserror = 0;

// cleaning the post variables
function clean_var($variable) {$variable = strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(rtrim($variable))));return $variable;}

// validation of filled form
if ( empty($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
$iserror = 1;
$alert .= "<li>" . $emptyname . "</li>";
} elseif ( ereg( "[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['name'] ) ) {
$iserror = 1;
$alert .= "<li>" . $alertname . "</li>";
}


if ( empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
$iserror = 1;
$alert .= "<li>" . $emptyemail . "</li>";
} elseif ( !eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_REQUEST['email']) ) {
$iserror = 1;
$alert .= "<li>" . $alertemail . "</li>";
}

if ( empty($_REQUEST['message']) ) {
$iserror = 1;
$alert .= "<li>" . $emptymessage . "</li>";
} elseif ( ereg( "[][{}*+\\^|]", $_REQUEST['message'] ) ) {
$iserror = 1;
$alert .= "<li>" . $alertmessage . "</li>";
}

// if there was error, print alert message
if ( $iserror==1 ) {

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(\".message\").hide(\"slow\").fadeIn(\"slow\").delay(5000).fadeOut(\"slow\"); </script>";
echo "<strong>" . $iserrormessage . "</strong>";
echo "<ul>";
echo $alert;
echo "</ul>";

} else {
// if everything went fine, send e-mail

$msg = "From: " . clean_var($_REQUEST['name']) . "\n";
$msg .= "Email: " . clean_var($_REQUEST['email']) . "\n";
$msg .= "Message: \n" . clean_var($_REQUEST['message']);
$header = 'From:'. clean_var($_REQUEST['email']);

mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $header);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(\".message\").fadeOut(\"slow\").fadeIn(\"slow\").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut(\"slow\");</script>";
echo $thanks;

die();
}
?>
```

im using the standard jquery.form.js (as far as i know)

thanks again in advance!

Comment: ereg depreciated, i assume you got this from some site, find a newer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your actual site, I see that not all you JS includes are being found in the folders you specify.  In particular this is the case for `jquery.form.js`.  Since this plugin is not found, the page naturally refreshes when you submit the form.

Looking at the HTML, I found this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ajaxcontactform/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

If you look for `http://www.robergeaz.com/js/ajaxcontactform/jquery.form.js`, you will see that it does not exist.

Looking at you other JS locations I see that most of them use the relative path `js/xyz.js`, which is equivalent to `http://www.robergeaz.com/darin/js/xyz.js`.  Using the same relative path as the other plugins for your form plugin shows a valid location at `http://www.robergeaz.com/darin/js/ajaxcontactform/jquery.form.js`.

So to solve your problem, change the above script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxcontactform/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Note the missing `/` at the beginning of the `src`.

Edit:

Also, you need to load the plugins AFTER you include the main jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

Do you importing the jquery lib?
Try to put it in your code head.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeah, its in there. still showing the error and its still leaving the page when a message is sent :(

Comment: Did you take a look at the console... I see several errors, most importantly the one that says that `jquery.form.js` was not found on the server (or at least not at the location that you provided).

Comment: yeah, its for sure uploaded. not sure why you arnt seeing it. its in my js folder

Comment: It might be uploaded, but it is not being found where you direct the browser to... are you saying you are not getting a console error?

Comment: @DarinSD are you calling the jquery lib before your jquery.form.js ??

Comment: After your page load, try to open your Console, and type just alert($); it should popup function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} if jquery is loaded, or undefined if not

Comment: Looking at your standard locations for all you JS code, it looks like you are using different directories.  Most of you JS is in `js/`, while you are using `/js/ajaxconactform/jquery.form.js`.  Note the `/` before the `js/`

Comment: @Guerra, yes, i am calling the lib before the form. should i not be doing that?